# Only base method of generic called

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following "models":

My base class:

```
public abstract class Search : Model
{
    //Properties ...

    public void ShallowCopy(Search reference)
    {
        base.ShallowCopy(reference);

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

My inheriting class:

```
public class Vehicle : Search
{
    //Properties

    public void ShallowCopy(Vehicle reference)
    {
        base.ShallowCopy(reference);

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

My base "viewModel" is generic:

```
public abstract class MasterDataWithoutAddressViewModel<TPrimaryModel> : MasterDataViewModel<TPrimaryModel> 
    where TPrimaryModel : Search, new()
{
    public void JustAMethod() 
    {
        //do stuff

        foreach (TPrimaryModel primaryModel in primaryModels)
        {
            TPrimaryModel primaryModelCopy = new TPrimaryModel();
            primaryModelCopy.ShallowCopy(primaryModel);
            //Do more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

My inheriting "viewModel":

```
public class VehicleViewModel : MasterDataWithoutAddressViewModel<Vehicle>
{
    //...
}
```

With `primaryModelCopy.ShallowCopy(primaryModel);` I expected the ShallowCopy of `Vehicle` to be called. However just the method of the base class `Search` is called. Debugger shows that `primaryModel` and `primaryModelCopy` are both from the correct type (`Vehicle`).

This is the complete inheritance hierarchy of my "models":
[image: Inheritance tree]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you have a compile time collision (due to the way overload resolution behaves) between methods with the same signature in your base and derived classes.

You need to declare your method `virtual`, and `override` them in derived classes:

Base:

```
public virtual void ShallowCopy(Search reference)
{
    base.ShallowCopy(reference);

    //Do stuff
}
```

Derived:

```
public override void ShallowCopy(Search reference)
{
    base.ShallowCopy(reference);

    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Using `Search reference` as parameter in the derived class doesn't seem to be right to me. Because I want to access properties which only exist in `Vehicle`, but not in `Search`. And I even have a more complex inheritance tree as I showed here (for simplicity).

Comment: @mosquito87 You can always accept a generic argument `T` which will be of the derived type. For example `public override void ShallowCopy<T>(T ofSearchType) where T : Search`. Or perhaps declare the class as generic.

Comment: My models aren't generic (and can't be).

Comment: Your models don't have to be generic, only your `ShallowCopy` method.

Comment: I've used your suggestion (although it results in the need to cast) and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution is performed at compile-time, and in `JustAMethod` it's performed *once*, not once per type-argument. So `primaryModelCopy.ShallowCopy` is resolved to the `Search.ShallowCopy` method.

There are two options here:

- You could use normal polymorphism, making `Search.ShallowCopy` virtual, and overriding it in `Vehicle.ShallowCopy` (which would need to cast the parameter back to `Vehicle` in the method)
- You could use dynamic typing in `JustAMethod` to perform overload resolution at execution-time instead. (This doesn't feel like a good idea to me, but it's an option.)

Comment: According the cast: The problem is that in my real project I have a more complex inheritance hierarchy. Casting feels like a pain to me here.

Comment: And I still don't get why `primaryModelCopy.ShallowCopy` is resolved to `Search.ShallowCopy`. I inherit from the viewModel with `public class VehicleViewModel : MasterDataWithoutAddressViewModel<Vehicle>`. Doesn't this tell that my `primaryModel` should be a `Vehicle` and not just a `Search`?

Comment: @mosquito87: no, it doesn't. When your `MasterDataWithoutAddressViewModel` class is compiled, , the compiler has no mean of knowing that its type argument will have the `ShallowCopy` method shadowed by another method with the same name, so it just links to the method it  knows. Use a virtual method if you want to override an implementation.

Comment: @mosquito87: As I said, `JustAMethod` method is compiled *once*, and overload resolution is performed at that point. It's not compiled every time you use it with a different type argument - so it *can't* compile to call `ShallowCopy(Vehicle)`. (That would be incorrect for different type arguments.)

Comment: @mosquito87 : notice how the compiler gives you a warning when you delared your `Vehicle.ShallowCopy` method without making it an override or declaring it `new`. The compiler told you what would happen. You should listen to it.

Comment: @Falanwe: No, it won't, because it's an overload - it has a different parameter type.